# Pass an object while submitting a form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I have something like this in my Controller.

```
public ActionResult GetResult(Employee employee){
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
}
```

I cannot use an Ajax Call because it will do a post and wait for a response, not a submit.

When I have something like this, it works.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetResult(string firstName,string lastName){
  return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
}


In javascript 


   var form = $("#Employee);
   form.attr('action','Employee/Index?firstName='Tim'&lastName='Tom');
   form.submit();
```

The above works when passing parameters as querystring.But I don't know how to pass an object while doing post. I tried using $.post. But it did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: If `Employee` contains properties `firstName` and `lastName` then then `public ActionResult GetResult(Employee employee)` will work but why do you not have controls for the properties?

Comment: How can I pass an object in QueryString? I believe 'Employee/Index?employee=objectEmployee' is not possible.

Comment: No of course not (Http knows nothing about c# classes). But `form.attr('action','Employee/Index?firstName='Tim'&lastName='Tom');` works if `Employee` contains those 2 properties. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to pass an object while doing a post. I have a class which has 20 fields. I cannot pass all those 20 parameters as querystring. Instead I want to pass an object.

Comment: But why are your creating a query string with those values? If its a form with inputs for editing the properties then that will bind to your model automatically. If your trying to pass back something to identify another model, then pass back only its ID and get the model from the repository. And the only way you can pass something from the client to the server is through key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a girid and a button. When the user selects a row and hits the button, I need to pass the entire row to the controller. How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of grid?  Reason I ask is some grid controls have a selected row method that will fetch it for you in JavaScript.  From there, you could pass that object back to the server.

Comment: Cool.  I can get that selected row. But can you tell me how to pass that to  the MVC controller?

Comment: I suggest you post the html generated by your view (just one row of the table is sufficient) so we can understand what you trying to do.

Comment: lets say I have 20 rows in my grid and I use jqGrid. If I want to just pass the entire row back to MVCController and do submit the form, how will I do? as per my question, I want to do this                                                                                               public ActionResult GetResult(Employee employee){
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
}                                                                                and I want to call the above method from javascript. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you editing data, then you need to use ajax and build the data to send it to the controller. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638308/data-posted-with-jquery-post-to-asp-net-4-mvc-2-as-null/26642485#26642485). Note ajax calls stay on the same page so `RedirectToAction` in your controller wont work. You will need to do a redirect using javascript `window.location.href=...`. I don't know anything about jqGrid, but it may have functions to make this easier.

Comment: Yes right. Ajax calls stay on the same page. So am looking for a way to pass object using form submit. Even if I use window. Location. Href, I will not be able to pass an object.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery POST in MVC works this way:

Since your controller action method is:

```
public ActionResult GetResult(Employee employee)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
}
```

You might want your modify your Jquery POST call this way

```
 var postData=function()
    {

        //prepare javascript object
                var employee=
                {
                  firstName:"firstname",
                  lastName:"lastname"
                };
        $.post('/GetResult',employee,function(data){
        //process the data here using the the data present in data obj
        });
     }
```

Model binder in mvc checks for the same paramters in the javascript object with the model which you have & and it should also match the parameter name of the action method to the javascript object name.

Let me know if this works out for you.

Thanks