# data posted with jquery post to Asp.net 4 Mvc 2 as null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery 1.8 to post data to ASP.Net 4 MVC 2 like this

```
PostData('Home/Login',{ "username": $("#username").val(),"password": $("#password").val()})

   function PostData(url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data:data,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            Success:successFunction, Error: ErrorFunction
        });
    };
```

My model

```
namespace FmsMvc.Models
{
    public class UsersModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime ts { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
    }

}
```

My Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Login(UsersModel u)
 {
     if (doSomething(Prop1, Prop2)
         return Json(null); // Success
     return Json(new { Status:'success',Msg:" Your username"+u.username });
 }
```

My controller does not get the data. It gets null when debugging.

what am i doing wrong?

**NOTE**

I deleted all the javascript in the Scripts folder, as I am using a custom script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, i found the culprit

in my ajax function above i have this two line

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType:'json',
```

Somehow, this should not be. when i submitted the form with the two lines present, this is what i saw in chrome dev

[image: bad request]

But when i removed the line `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, so that the $.ajax is now

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        type: 'post', // GET or POST
        url: url, // the file to call
        dataType:'json',
        data: data, // get the form data
        Success:successFunction, Error: ErrorFunction
     });
```

when i look in chrome dev after submit, i see this, which was not there before

[image: good resp]

I dont' know why this is the case, i will try in other browsers to see if it all works

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JSON.strinfigy-ing your data before POSTing?

```
function PostData(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        Success:successFunction, Error: ErrorFunction
    });
};
```

Comment: What JSON.stringify(data) does?

Comment: it converts your data in to a string representation.  MVC (Json.NET) will deserialize the data for you at the controller.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZeeshan I just did, but still get null

Comment: Apart from JSON.stringify you need to make sure the property name should match exactly with server side model

Comment: @PankajDey is correct.  Your property names are all lowercase, and they should match your model.

Comment: @PankajDey Is it necessary to keep all the scripts in the Scripts folder, I though it might be the cause, so i just deleted them now

Comment: @Smith MVC doesn't care where your scripts are located as long as they are where you say they are.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
var data = { "username": $("#username").val(),
             "password": $("#password").val()
           };
PostData('Home/Login',JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I just did, but still get null

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery `.post()` method which will parse the values for you

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")'; // beter to use this rather than hardcoding
var userName = `$("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
$.post(url, { Username: userName, Password: password }, function(result) {
  // do something with the result you returned from the action method
  alert(result.Msg);
});
```

Note, only properties `Username` and `Password` will be set in the model. The other properties will be their default values.

Comment: `$.post()` is just a shortcut. [Refer documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: what is wrong with $.ajax, also i cannot set my success and error handler, which is very important

Comment: The 3rd parameter is the `success` callback. If your controller throws an exception, return `Json(null)` then in your success callback, test `if(result) { ..do something.. } else { ..oops..};